# Стеганография, текст в BMP файл ((смена палитры))

Tags: графика, цвета, bmp, стеганография

Господа, приветствую!

**[не замена бита (LSB метод)]**

Наткнулся вот на такой бложик http://www.nestego.ru/2012/07/blog-post_31.html

С созданием алфавита все понятно a = 0, b=1...z = 26; 
но как быть с "Далее проводится замена цветов палитры. Для этого первому 51 цвету палитры назначается черный цвет (цвет рисунка). Следующему 51 цвету палитры назначается белый цвет (цвет фона)."

Если говорить о простой реализации на каком-нибудь квадрате малевича, то как это сделать ? (("сменить" эту палитру)

Не смог найти информацию о смене палитры от слова совсем, врядли это связано с ЯП (питон) т.к. на других ЯП не нашел "смены палитры", из англоязычных источников нашел лишь рваную пдф где говорится о томже, о чем написано в приведенном выше блоге, пдф звалась`Mapping pixel to letters` - https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Image-Steganography-by-Mapping-Pixels-to-Letters-Al-Husainy/2f265f1f86f0d2af82e697d53aad360c696c3830

Comment: В статье по первой ссылке объясняется что такое палитра. По сути это массив элементов по 3 байта. Как менять палитру - зависит от формата рисунка (bmp, gif, png). Причем в bmp и png рисунок может быть сохранен вообще без палитры (с такими рисунками метод из статьи не будет работать). Как конкретно менять - ищите спецификацию выбранного формата, смотрите где находится палитра, меняете ее.

Comment: Я не смог найти как это все выглядит, писать в духе black = 255,255,255 не помогает